# Self contained generic

Tags: swift, generics

i have the following protocol:

```
public protocol ImagesContainer {
    associatedtype ImageName: RawRepresentable where ImageName.RawValue == String
    static var bundle: Bundle? { get }
}
```

with an implementation like this

```
struct ImagesMain: ImagesContainer {
    public static var bundle: Bundle? { return .main }
    public enum ImageName: String {
        case loading, success, error
        case profile, address
    }
}

struct ImagesUser: ImagesContainer {
    public static var bundle: Bundle? { return .main }
    public enum ImageName: String {
        case profile, address, country
    }
}
```

so usually I have used that in model structs

```
struct ViewModel {
    let icon: ImagesMain.ImageName
}
```

which is fine for one `ImagesContainer`. But I have one such container for each bundle and I would like to mix and match them when creating those ViewModels. For now they are always tied to one `ImagesContainer`. I would like to generalize that, so that I can specify any ImageName from any `ImagesContainer`.

something like

```
struct ViewModel {
    let profileIcon<T: ImagesContainer>: (T, T.ImageName)
    let addressIcon<T: ImagesContainer>: (T, T.ImageName)

}
```

I can't put this on the struct itself, because there may be multiple properties with different `ImagesContainer`s and so on. Is there a way to have a self-contained generic?

Comment: To be honest, this looks a bit complicated. I would probably make `ImagesContainer: RawRepresentable` and make that protocol implemented by the enums. Then you wouldn't need an associated type at all and all your problems would go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who is interested in a solution, here is what I came up with.

```
public protocol ImageAsset {
    func image() -> UIImage
}

private struct DefaultImageAsset<T: ImageAssetsContainer>: ImageAsset {
    let container: T.Type
    let imageName: T.ImageName

    init(_ container: T.Type, _ imageName: T.ImageName) {
        self.container = container
        self.imageName = imageName
    }

    func image() -> UIImage {
        return container.image(imageName)
    }
}
```

so the actual logic is within the struct and the type is not communicated to the outside:

```
struct ViewModel {
    let profileIcon: ImageAsset
    let addressIcon: ImageAsset
}

let viewModel = ViewModel(
     profilesIcon: DefaultImageAsset(ImagesMain.self, .profile),
     addressIcon: DefaultImageAsset(ImagesUser.self, .address)
)

viewModel.profilesIcon.image()
```